# grouped table view like iphone contacts

Tags: iphone

I'm new to Xcode and I'm trying to create an app which has a tableview. Ideally it should look pretty similar to the standard contacts app on iphone/ipod touch. So the tableview should show the names of my friends, and the detail view should show address, email, phone number and a picture etc. The only difference is that the user shouldn't be able to edit the adresses. So it's more like a directory. I would like to do this with a .plist-file as I don't want to create 200 detailviews......I've already watched a dozen tutorials on tableviews, but none of them is close enough to what I'm looking for.... Can anyone explain me how to do this? Or do you have a tutorial on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question asks for a lot so the best I could do is give a general overview of it. You are going to need to create custom cells for your tableview. [This](http://s3.amazonaws.com/screencasts.pragmaticstudio.com/005_custom_cells_in_ib.mov) tutorial should start you off if using IB. You can also create your cells using code rather than IB. If your doing it on code you should create the view of the cell when creating the cell if the cell hasn't been created, then set the properties of the cell. There might be one or two examples on the net for this.

You can disable touches on a cell by doing:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

You are also going to want a transparent background for your first cell. I create my cells in code and to create a cell with a transparent background use

```
UIView *transparentBackground = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
transparentBackground.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.backgroundView = transparentBackground;
[transparentBackground release];
```

Once you have absorbed all that ask some more specific questions to help achieve your result.

Comment: Thanks a Lot but i found out a very good way is not to create custom cell instead put  a condition in number of sections to return with and also put a condition in cell for row at index Path Method and regarding the buttons which appear at the bottom I decided to Put in the UITableViewFooter Method. So I eventually got the solution but thanks a lot for a very good advice I will surely look forward to it